# How to define a `StrContains.unapply` for pattern match?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

There is a method in my code, which need to check if the passing string contain some specified chars, and then do something.

The code is looking like:

```
def check(str: String) = {
  if(str.contains("A")) {
    doSomething()
  } else if(str.contains("B")) {
    doSomething()
  } else if(str.contains("C")) {
    doSomething()
  } else {
    doSomething()
  }
}
```

I want to try pattern match on it, but not very satisfied with:

```
def check(str: String) = str match {
  case s if s.contains("A") => doSomething()
  case s if s.contains("B") => doSomething()
  case s if s.contains("C") => doSomething()
  case _ => doSomething()
}
```

I hope I can define a `StrContains.unapply` to use it like this:

```
def check(str: String) = str match {
  case StrContains("A") => doSomething()
  case StrContains("B") => doSomething()
  case StrContains("C") => doSomething()
  case _ => doSomething()
}
```

But now sure how to do it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you do `case StrContains("A")`, the compiler will first call `StrContains.unapply/unapplySeq` (whichever way it is defined) and only then  try to match the returned result against `"A"`. The `"A"` literal itself will never be passed to `StrContains.unapply/unapplySeq`, so it has no way to perform the call `s.contains("A")` inside `unapply/unapplySeq`.

Simply put, this means you'd need to define distinct objects such as `StrContainsA`/`StrContainsB`/`StrContainsC` which is clearly a worse situation than simply doing `case s if s.contains("A")`.

However, there is an alternative (and somewhat contrived) solution that allows to define a single extractor while still being able to specify **inline** the substring to match for, and that is to exploit the fact that scala supports defining extractors based on string interpolation:

```
implicit class ContainsContext (val sc : StringContext) {
  object StrContains {
    def unapply(str: String): Boolean = {
      val substr: String = sc.parts.mkString
      str.contains(substr)
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
def check(str: String) = str match {
  case StrContains"A" => doSomething()
  case StrContains"B" => doSomething()
  case StrContains"C" => doSomething()
  case _ => doSomething()
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to do `case StrContains("A")()` where the first call returns a matcher object and the second is the `unapply`?

Comment: Sorry but no, I don't see how it could be done, for the reasons I gave at the beginning of my answer.